# Python json encode with same keys (solr)

Tags: python, json, encoding, solr

*I am creating client, which sent json encoded data to server*

**Data example:**

```
{ 
"add": {
  "doc": {
    "id": "DOC1",
    "my_boosted_field": {
      "boost": 2.3,
      "value": "test"
    },
    "my_multivalued_field": [ "aaa", "bbb" ]
  }
},
"add": {
  "commitWithin": 5000,
  "overwrite": false,uniqueKey */
  "boost": 3.45,
  "doc": {
    "f1": "v1",
    "f1": "v2"
  }
},

"commit": {},
"optimize": { "waitFlush":false, "waitSearcher":false },

"delete": { "id":"ID" },
"delete": { "query":"QUERY" }
"delete": { "query":"QUERY", 'commitWithin':'500' }
}
```

*As you can see, there is 2 dict's with 'add' key ant and 3 dict's with 'delete' keys. **How its posible?***

I am encoding data with:

```
data = {}
data['delete'] = delete1
data['delete'] = delete2
data['delete'] = delete3
print json.dumps(data)
```

**but it encodes only delete3!**

So how to create JSON response with same keys? json.dumps maybe can encode dict with same keys, but how to create them in Python? Python dict key is unique...

**Thanks for the help!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries have *unique* keys. JSON objects SHOULD have unique names, but the SOLR sample you found violates that. Quoting from the [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2):

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

Because in Python dictionaries, names **are** unique, you *cannot* use the standard `json` library to generate the output you have shown.

You'll have to roll your own encoder if you require that specific output. I'd generate a list of tuples of `(action, dictionary)` pairs, then encode the dictionaries with the `json` library and then use string templating for the last step:

```
data = []
data.append(('delete', delete1))
data.append(('delete', delete2))
data.append(('delete', delete3))

output = '{%s}' % ',\n'.join(['"{}": {}'.format(action, json.dumps(dictionary)) for action, dictionary in data])
```

This approach is a *little* fragile in that it doesn't ensure `action` values are escaped according to JSON rules, but as long as the action values are simple ASCII strings without quotes it'll work just fine. You can always add encoding to `unicode_escape` and manually escaping any `"` characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> delete1 = { "id":"ID" }
>>> delete2 = { "query":"QUERY" }
>>> delete3 = { "query":"QUERY", 'commitWithin':'500' }
>>> data = []
>>> data.append(('delete', delete1))
>>> data.append(('delete', delete2))
>>> data.append(('delete', delete3))
>>> '{%s}' % ',\n'.join(['"{}": {}'.format(action, json.dumps(dictionary)) for action, dictionary in data])
'{"delete": {"id": "ID"},\n"delete": {"query": "QUERY"},\n"delete": {"query": "QUERY", "commitWithin": "500"}}'
>>> print '{%s}' % ',\n'.join(['"{}": {}'.format(action, json.dumps(dictionary)) for action, dictionary in data])
{"delete": {"id": "ID"},
"delete": {"query": "QUERY"},
"delete": {"query": "QUERY", "commitWithin": "500"}}
```

Comment: It seems IBM is abusing JSON RFC. The official tutorial from IBM Bluemix shows the data being encoded in this way.

Comment: @pmuntima: `SHOULD` is a very specific term in RFCs, see [RFC 2119](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119); it means 'strongly recommended'. As such, it is technically not a violation of the RFC when someone deviates.